# Best Practice to Load Data from API when navigating to page?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I'm developing a UWP app which gets list of trending anime with its profile picture which is binded to a horizontal `ListView`. I've made my API call in `Page_Loaded` event. The problem is, as soon as navigating to that page, the content is loaded but the layout didn't updated the ListView. Am I doing something wrong. If I'm wrong, then what is the correct procedure to call the API request and to Bind the data to ListView?

This is my Data Class:

```cs
    public class AnimeObject
    {
        public string Title {get; set;}
        public string coverImage {get; set}
        public int totalEpisodes {get; set}
    }
```

And, this is my `Page_Loaded` Event:

```cs
    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView.ItemsSource = await apiHandler.RequestAPI();
    }
```

Here, the `RequestAPI` Function is returning `List<AnimeObject>` and the ListView is simply a datatemplate, which is least to worry.

**Edit:**

As [Nico Zhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254781/nico-zhu-msft) asked, I've provided a sample code. This code contains api which is a graphql API.

MainPage.xaml:

```xml
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind animeDetails.data.Page.media[0].title}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind animeDetails.data.Page.media[0].id}"/>
    <Image Source="{x:Bind animeDetails.data.Page.media[0].coverImage}"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
namespace TestAppForNotify
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public dataClass.AnimeObject animeDetails;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            animeDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dataClass.AnimeObject>(
                await requestAPI()
            );
        }

        private async Task<string> requestAPI()
        {
            string query = @"
            query{
              Page(perPage: 20, page: 1){
                media(sort: TRENDING_DESC){
                  id
                  title{
                    english
                  }
                  coverImage {
                    extraLarge
                  }
                }
              }
            }";

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var jsonString = new StringContent(
                JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                    new
                    {
                        query = query
                    }
                ),
                System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json"
            );

            var request = await client
                .PostAsync("https://graphql.anilist.co", jsonString);

            var response = await request
                .Content
                .ReadAsStringAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine(response);

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I've used Newtonsoft.Json for json Serializing..

Please Help me...

Comment: Can you set debug point in line `await apiHandler.RequestAPI()` to check if it could return correct value?

Comment: It's returning the appropriate value, but the xaml is not updating...

Comment: can you make simple sample for us? I will test base on your demo.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've attached my sample code above. please feel free to check...

Comment: You should add list ItemsSource like this  `AnimeList.ItemsSource = animeDetails.data.Page.media;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks you bind wrong property, please edit your binding like the following.

```
<ListView x:Name=" " Margin="0,50,0,0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Background="White">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title.english, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding id, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Image Source="{Binding coverImage.extraLarge, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="Visible" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   
     animeDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.AnimeObject>(
           await requestAPI()
       );
    AnimeList.ItemsSource = animeDetails.data.Page.media;
}
```

**Update**

```
private Model.AnimeObject _animeDetails;
public Model.AnimeObject animeDetails
{
    get { return _animeDetails; }
    set
    {
        _animeDetails = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Xaml Code

```
<StackPanel
    Width="300"
    Height="300"
    Background="White">
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind animeDetails.data.Page.media[1].title.english, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind animeDetails.data.Page.media[1].id, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Image Source="{x:Bind animeDetails.data.Page.media[1].coverImage.extraLarge, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: My Doubt is in `MainPage.xaml.cs`, the variable `animeDetails` is not initialized and is null at starting. Afterwards, when the `Page_Loaded` event is triggered, the variable `animeDetails` is initialized and is not null. But the binding property is binding the data of the uninitialized `animeDetails` (i.e) it binded the elements before the `Page_Loaded` event gets triggered. how to notify the xaml to update the elements that the data is changed??

Comment: I think you need implement  OnPropertyChanged for `animeDetails` please refer case update.

Comment: How can I do that??

Comment: Please refer to  this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=winrt-22000).